# $n$ complex numbers with modulus $1$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

> **The problem:** Let $z_1$,$z_2$,...$z_n$ $(n \geq 3)$ be complex numbers such that $\left| z_1 \right|=\left| z_2 \right|=\ldots=\left| z_n \right|=1$. Then show that the following statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. These are the vertices of a regular polygon.
> 2. ${z_1}^n+{z_2}^n+\ldots+{z_n}^n=n(-1)^{n+1} z_1 z_2 \ldots z_n$

**My approach:** We can visualize the numbers as points on a circle with radius $1$. Now, if $(1)$ is true, then difference of arguments between two adjacent vertices would be equal to $\frac{2 \pi}{n}$. W.L.O.G., we can assume that $\arg(z_1)<\arg(z_2)<\ldots <\arg(z_n)$. Let $z_1=e^{i\theta}$. Then, $z_2=e^{i(\theta+\frac{2\pi}{n})}=e^{i \theta}\cdot e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$ and $z_r=e^{i \theta}\cdot e^{\frac{2\pi i(r-1)}{n}}\; \text{for}\; r=1,2,\ldots n$.

So, $$\begin{align} {z_1}^n+{z_2}^n+\ldots+{z_n}^n &= e^{in\theta}(1+1+\ldots+1)\\
&=ne^{in\theta}\end{align}$$

And, $$\begin{align} n(-1)^{n+1} z_1 z_2 \ldots z_n &= n(-1)^{n+1}e^{in\theta}\cdot e^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\cdot \frac{2\pi i}{n}}\\
&= n(-1)^{n+1}e^{in\theta}\cdot {(e^{i\pi})}^{(n+1)}\\
&= n(-1)^{n+1}e^{in\theta}\cdot (-1)^{(n+1)}\\
&= ne^{in\theta}\cdot \end{align}$$
So, I've managed to prove that the first condition implies the second. But, I've no idea how to prove it the other way around. Any help would be qppreciated.

Comment: If $n$ is odd, then isn't $z_i=1$ for $i=1\ldots n$ a counterexample? Should claim #2 be strengthened by quantifying for all natural numbers $n$ or something?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Let's say a point is a regular polygon of the order zero.

Comment: Okay, that works.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs And also, $n \geq 3$

Comment: From $(2)$ we get
$$|z_1^n+...+z_n^n|=n.$$
Since $|z_i^n|=1$ we must have that $z_1^n=z_2^n=...=z_n^n$

Comment: @mrprottolo So, we can say that these are the $n$th roots of $1$ multiplied by some constant.

Comment: The product of the ${n^{th}}$ roots of 1 is 1 or -1, depending on value of n. If n is even the product is 1. If n is odd it is -1. Weird, but easy to prove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let us assume $z_1^n + .. + z_n^n = n(-1)^{n+1}z_1..z_n $. Then, $|z_1^n + .. + z_n^n| = n = |z_1^n| + .. + |z_n^n| $. 
>
> So, since we are summing $n$ complex numbers of module $1$, then $ z_1^n, .., z_n^n $ all have the same argument.

I let you finish...

Comment: So, we can say that these are the $n$th roots of $1$ multiplied by some constant.